# How do I prove that the standard definition of prime ideal is equivalent to that of Krull's?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Definition
>
> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$. Then $I$ is prime if and only if $\forall a,b\in I, a\in I$ or $b\in I$.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$.

Let $I,J$ be ideals of $R$ such that $IJ\subset P$.

How do I prove that $I\subset P$ or $J\subset P$? (which is the Krull's definition)?

Comment: Please use the search feature first, next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I,J,P$ be ideals such that $IJ\subseteq P$. Suppose that $I\not\subseteq P$ and $J\not\subseteq P$. Then there exists $x\in I$ and $y\in J$ such that $x,y\notin P$. Because $IJ\subseteq P$, we have $xy\in P$. Hence, $P$ is not prime.